# ActionScript 3.0 - Line Gradient Positioning?

Tags: actionscript-3, matrix, line, gradient

i'm drawing a line with a gradient style, but for some reason the line's `x` position appears to be about 4 or 5 instead of 0 when added to the display list.  tracing the line's `x` postion returns `0`, but it's clearly visible that the line is not positioned at that coordinate.

if i remove the gradient box then it is positioned correctly, but that's not a solution since i would lose the gradient.

i'm targeting FlashPlayer 11 / AIR 3 using Flash Builder.  any ideas?

```
//Constants
private static const LINE_COLOR:uint = 0xFFFFFF;
private static const LINE_WIDTH:uint = 10;

//Variables
private var volumeLineShape:Shape = new Shape();
private var volumeLineMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix();

// ~

volumeLineMatrix.createGradientBox(widthProperty, heightProperty);

volumeLineShape.graphics.clear();
volumeLineShape.graphics.lineStyle(LINE_WIDTH, 0, 1.0, false, LineScaleMode.NONE, CapsStyle.NONE);
volumeLineShape.graphics.lineGradientStyle(GradientType.LINEAR, [LINE_COLOR, LINE_COLOR, LINE_COLOR], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0, 255 * toneProperty, 255], volumeLineMatrix);
volumeLineShape.graphics.moveTo(0, heightProperty - heightProperty * volumeProperty);
volumeLineShape.graphics.lineTo(widthProperty, heightProperty - heightProperty * volumeProperty);
```

Comment: I'm confused, what do you expect your gradient line to look like? I think the problem might be with the ´lineGradientStyle´ parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a banding problem.  setting zero position at alpha 0 and another zero position at alpha 1 causes issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just gived some static values to width and position, and it drawed a line that left corner and line is transparent at corner. Check your values and change your background to see white transparent part of line.

```
volumeLineShape.graphics.clear();
volumeLineShape.graphics.lineStyle(LINE_WIDTH, 0, 1.0, false, LineScaleMode.NONE, CapsStyle.NONE);
volumeLineShape.graphics.lineGradientStyle(GradientType.LINEAR, [LINE_COLOR, LINE_COLOR, LINE_COLOR], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0, 255 * toneProperty, 255], volumeLineMatrix);
volumeLineShape.graphics.moveTo(0, 0);
volumeLineShape.graphics.lineTo(100, 100);
```